# Add values of n number of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of arrays containing values, it looks something like this

```
var values = [[23,45,12,67],[26,35,65,23],[45,73,12,54],[32,45,65,86]];
```

I want to add all the arrays present inside `values` variable such like

```
sum = [126,198,154,230]
```

126 = 23+26+45+32

198 = 45+35+73+45

I tried this using `Array.prototype.map()` but maybe I am not getting the perfect logic to do that so needed help here. How to add the values of n arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, you could map the sum of single values, but you need to reduce the arrays as well.

```js
var values = [[23, 45, 12, 67], [26, 35, 65, 23], [45, 73, 12, 54], [32, 45, 65, 86]],
    result = values.reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very nice logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#forEach`. Iterate over your array, for each array inside the array, sum its value in a new array and add the other arrays to result based on the index.

```js
var values = [[23,45,12,67],[26,35,65,23],[45,73,12,54],[32,45,65,86]],
    result = values.reduce((r,a) => {
      a.forEach((v,i) => r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + v);
      return r;
    }); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```js
const values = [[23,45,12,67],[26,35,65,23],[45,73,12,54],[32,45,65,86]];

const res = values.reduce((curr, next) => {

  let length = curr.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    curr[i] += next[i]
  }
  return curr;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code some what like this,

```
var sum;
var values = [[23,45,12,67],[26,35,65,23],[45,73,12,54],[32,45,65,86]];
values.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
     item..forEach(ArraySum)
}

function ArraySum(item, index) {
     sum=sum+item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code example:

```js
const values = [[23, 45, 12, 67], [26, 35, 65, 23], [45, 73, 12, 54], [32, 45, 65, 86]];
const result = values.map((v, index, array) => v.reduce((a, c, i) => a + array[i][index], 0));
    
console.log(result);
```